# Get all posts from custom post type and insert in select input as metabox

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, post-meta, select, input

I would like to know if its possible to do something like this. I have **Slider** custom post type and **Services** custom post type.

For slider posts I have created a metabox for URL value to display next to all slider posts. What I would like to do now, is to get all posts from **Services custom post type**, and display them in this slider post metabox as select input, so I can choose which post should the link go to.

Thanks in advance :)

Here is the current code:

```
function rm_display_slider_metabox($post) {

    wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__), 'slider_nonce');

    $slide_url_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_slide_url', true);
    $slide_url = isset($slide_url_value) ? esc_attr($slide_url_value) : '';

    $services_loop = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'services',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_status' => 'publish'
    ));


?>
    <div class="slider meta">
        <p>
            <label for="slide-url"><?php _e('Select URL from the dropdown below for this slide', 'rmtheme' ); ?></label>
            <br />
            <select name="_slide_url">
                <?php while ($services_loop->have_posts()) : $services_loop->the_post(); ?>
                    <option value="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </select>
        </p>
    </div>

<?php 

}

function rm_save_slider_meta($post) {

    global $post;

    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return $post_id;

    if (!isset($_POST['slider_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['slider_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))
        return $post_id;

    if (!current_user_can('edit_post'))
        return $post_id;

    $allowed = array(   
        'a' => array(
            'href' => array()
        )  
    );

    if (isset($_POST['_slide_url']))
        update_post_meta($post->ID, '_slide_url', wp_kses($_POST['_slide_url'], $allowed));

}

add_action('save_post', 'rm_save_slider_meta');
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'rm_slider_metabox');
```

Answer (score 3):

(0. Retrieve the meta value with `get_post_custom` (in order to highlight the selected value in the select input).)

1. Query posts with `get_posts( array(  'post_type' => 'services', 'post_status' => 'publish' ) )`
2. Loop through the results with `foreach` and build your select input.
3. Hook into save_post (`add_action('save_post', 'my_save_meta')` to store the selected value (with `update_post_meta`).

Comment: I added my current code to the original post. But Im getting Notice: Undefined variable error: Check the image here: http://img31.imageshack.us/img31/8192/bbrt.png

Comment: Try changing `rm_save_slider_meta($post)` to `rm_save_slider_meta($post_id)`?

Comment: That got rid of the first error. Should I also change that in services-post-type? Wont it break the code somehow? Btw that error only shows when creating new post. I guess its because the post->ID is not defined because the post is not yet saved. But when I save it it dissapears. The select seems to work. I get urls and they display on the homepage but when I save the select option  value is changed to the default - first post.

Comment: 1. change that in services-post-type: not sure what you mean - all I know is that the `save_post` hook takes the ID as a parameter. 2. Select changed to default upon save: you need to add 'selected' to the `<option>` with the same URL as the one you retrieved with get_post_meta.

Comment: Also, personally I wouldn't store the permalink as the meta value, but the ID of the Services post. Code for selected option would then be something like `<option value="<?php the_ID();?>" <?php if($slide_ID ==  get_the_ID()) { echo " selected" }?> ><?php the_title(); ?></option>`

Comment: Sorry Im kinda noob in this stuff. I think there is just a little more work needed. Currently my code is: 

$slide_url = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_slide_url', true);
$slide_ID = get_the_ID();

So First Im getting current value from slide url. ANd then I create variable for $slide_ID and this is equal to slide post ID. Is this correct? Next thing is the option, I dont know what code to use there. Or basically what to do next.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11383/discussion-between-richard-misencik-and-ptriek)